# Query with iteration in Oracle pl/sql

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have the following table with a single column

```
Z_NUM  
--------
34545
345
656
32
42
...
```

I want to build a following dependence

```
i  | SUM(Z_NUM)
----------------
2  | 40934
3  | 51244
4  | 54793
...
```

based on query
`SELECT SUM(z_num) FROM table WHERE z_num < i;`

The variable `i` is a parameter and should be incremented by 1.
How to implement this query in ORACLE?

If I were doing this in MYSQL, I would write something like

```
SELECT
    ​@n := @n + 1 n,
    SUM(z_num)
FROM table, (SELECT @n := 1) m
WHERE z_num < n;
```

But unfortunately it does not work in Oracle PL/SQL.

Comment: In either database you need a column which provides the ordering for the cursor.

Answer (score 0):

Use two subqueries:

- one with `connect by` to generate numbers `i` from 2 to N
- another dependend subquery to calculate a sum for each `i`

---

```
SELECT i, 
       (  SELECT coalesce( sum(z_num), 0 )
          FROM table1 WHERE z_num < i 
       ) as myresult
FROM (
  SELECT level+1 As i FROM dual
  CONNECT BY LEVEL <= ( SELECT max(Z_NUM) FROM table1 )-1
)
ORDER BY i
```

Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c460c/5

Answer (score 0):

use ROWNUM,

```
SELECT SUM(z_num)
  FROM (SELECT z_num, rownum rown
          FROM table)
 WHERE z_num < rown;
```

OR

```
SELECT SUM(z_num)
  FROM (SELECT z_num, rownum rown
          FROM table)
 WHERE rown < 10;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT i, 
   (  SELECT coalesce( sum(z_num), 0 )
      FROM Table_NUM WHERE ROWNUM <= i 
   ) as SUM(Z_NUM)
FROM (
      SELECT level+1 As i FROM dual
      CONNECT BY LEVEL <= ( SELECT Max(ROWNUM) FROM Table_NUM )-1
   )
ORDER BY i;
```

Result:

```
I     SUM_RESULT
-----------------
2      34890
3      35546
4      35578
5      35620
```

It may be help you.